Does the Omnitemporal instantiation imply necessitarism?
I have a doubt about the relationship between property and its extent. Some philosophers (e.g. David Armstrong) when dealing with the problem of universals specify that they adopt a omnitemporal conception of instantiation. When arguing, for instance, that a universal exists if it is instantiated, the expression 'is' is assumed tò omnitemporally include the past, present and future instances of the universal itself. My doubt is this: does the omnitemporal conception of instantiation imply that the extension of a universal cannot be different from what it is? When I think of an instantiated universal in a omnitemporal sense I imagine its extension as already fixed once and for all.
